# How to use orWhere to create dynamic where clause - Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

how I can to write this in Eloquent and I'm uisng laravel 4?

```
SELECT * FROM `applicant` WHERE `id`='17' OR `id`='19'
```

I am thinking like this

```
$findIDAUTH = Auth::User()->id;
$findHrsbu = HrSbu::where('staff_id', '=', $findIDAUTH)->get();
$results = Mapplication::MApplication();
foreach($findHrsbu as $HrSbu){
    $results = $results->Where('sbu.id', '=', $HrSbu->sbu_id);
}
$results = $results->get();
```

if just

```
SELECT * FROM `applicant` WHERE `id`='17'
```

i'ts work but if

```
SELECT * FROM `applicant` WHERE `id`='17' OR `id`='19' or 'id'='20'
```

not working for me thanks

Comment: Is `Mapplication` an Eloquent model?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `whereIn` with a subquery:

```
$results = Mapplication::whereIn('id', function ($query) {
    $query->from((new HrSbu)->getTable())
          ->select('sbu_id')
          ->where('staff_id', auth()->id());
})->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi Please try with this code and let me know, here is an option by laravel as you used its a similar method....

```
$findIDAUTH  = Auth::User()->id;
$findHrsbu   = HrSbu::where('staff_id', '=', $findIDAUTH)->get();
$results =      Mapplication::MApplication()->where(function($findHrsbu)->where(function($results) use ($findHrsbu) {
foreach($findHrsbu as $HrSbu){ 
   $results->orWhere('sbu.id', '=', $HrSbu->sbu_id);
}
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hy guys thanks for your answer..
Problem solved I'm using WhereIn 
for ex : `$results->whereIn('sbu.id', '=', array($dataArray));`